# how to override TextField of floating label text and underline color in material-ui-next?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I got stuck with changing the color of floating label text and undeline using className, inputProps and InputLabelProps but the color doesn't change at all. It works when I set pallet primary with color using theme but I wanted to change the color on component level.

I followed all working demos [given here](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/). Below is what I have tried till now but color isn't changing

```
import React from "react";
import {
  TextField
} from "@material-ui/core";

const TextField = props => {
  const styles = theme => ({
    textField: {
      color: "red !important"
    },
    input: {
      color: "white !important"
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
            <TextField
              id="fName"
              label="First Name"
              className={classes.textField}
              inputProps={{
                className: classes.input
              }}
              InputLabelProps={{
                className: classes.input
              }}
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChange={this.handleFirstname('fName')}
              margin="normal"
            />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Well to start with, you're mixing usage here, and you've duplicated the name of your component with the provided component from material-ui.

You've called your new component `TextField` which is identical to the component provided by material-ui - their example expects the TextField to be named `TextFields` (plural)

Additionally you've called code that expects `withStyles` to be imported, and called on your component to make it a HOC, which would then provide the `props.classes` object your code expects (perhaps this is accounted for in your code, and your example simply didn't include it) - and styles should be created outside the component you are applying it to, so that you can provide it as a parameter to withStyles as you will see in my example below.

And finally, you've created a functional stateless component that calls state, which naturally cannot work.

Assuming your example code is complete, those three errors will need to be fixed.

I've crafted an example that works with hard coded values instead of state, which can be swapped as necessary if you wish to change this to a stateful component:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  textField: {
    color: "red !important"
  },
  input: {
    color: "black !important"
  }
});

const TextFields = withStyles(styles)(props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        id="fName"
        label="First Name"
        className={props.classes.textField}
        inputProps={{
          className: props.classes.textField
        }}
        InputLabelProps={{
          className: props.classes.input
        }}
        value="Hello!"
        //onChange={this.handleFirstname('fName')}
        margin="normal"
      />
    </div>
  );
});

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<TextFields />, document.getElementById("root"));
```